# Can you use AWS Glue Schema Registry with multiple schemas in the same Kafka topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-glue, aws-msk

Can you use AWS Glue Schema Registry with multiple schemas in the same Kafka topic? If so, does anyone have an example? I know there are examples to do so for the Confluent schema registry, but I want to avoid hosting our own schema registry.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to? What specific errors are you getting when you try?

Comment: I think what @Oxy means is there is only one constant for schema name. So how would you configure multiple? @OneCricketeer

As I understand the docs if iI want to produce from for example a kstream application, I configure my kafka client with some: AWSSchemaRegistryConstants, there is no obvious way to set multiple schema names there. 

`kafkaConfig[AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.SCHEMA_NAME] = "some schema"`

Answer (score 0):

If you dont provide the AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.SCHEMA_NAME

The registry uses transport name (topic name in case of Kafka)

ref [aws-glue-schema-registr github docs](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry/blob/master/README.md#providing-schema-name)

Comment: If using the same serializer for key and value, or with multiple topics, using a custom naming strategy class would be better